# Ideal Package(Folder) structure of an app implemented with mvvm pattern

Tags: android, mvvm, package

What should be "ideal" package or folder structure of an app in which MVVM pattern is used. Because different open source applications use different structure. Is there any specific good folder structure defined by google? Lets say Flower application of google has all the fragments in the root folder which maybe good for that application but for a bigger application which has dozens of activities and fragments ,I don't think it would be wise to keep all of them in root folder. So whats the better approach in this matter?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will find sth in [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched)